# Homestay in Sweden to learn Swedish

Tags: study, sweden, languages, homestay

I'm Dutch but in love with the Swedish language, so after some time on Duolingo I wanted to expand my knowledge of Swedish in real life. I found an organization which provides Swedish lessons in different Swedish cities for way cheaper than other organizations, simply because they don't provide any accommodation.

So, the idea was that I'd go to their classes and stay at a Swedish family: the perfect place to practice! But I found it rather difficult to find a homestay. I tried GoCambio, but they only offer one option in Sweden that isn't suitable, and I've looked at Workaway, but I'm not really the most suitable person to help paint a new organic farm.

Does anyone know any options or just has other ideas in general? I actually find the homestay more important than the teaching organization (because that seems to be the best way to learn the language), so I'm not bound to specific city or place.

Comment: You might look for short-term roommate situations; these are often targeted to students in higher education, of course.

Comment: AirBNB ?  BeWelcome.org is a non-profit alternative to CouchSurfing.  Smaller, but better (IMHO).  There's a new place like those called TrustRoots.org and WarmShowers.org is aimed at bicyclists.

Comment: Be prepared for [sju sjösjuka sjömän sköttes av sju sköna sjuksköterskor](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Sv-sju_sj%C3%B6sjuka_sj%C3%B6m%C3%A4n.ogg)

Comment: @pnuts care to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions from Comments (all mentioned by @WGroleau):

[couchsurfing.com](https://www.couchsurfing.com/places/europe/sweden/stockholm) Link is to Stockholm but there is also a page for Gothenburg.

[Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.co.uk/s/Sweden?guests=1&place_id=ChIJ8fA1bTmyXEYRYm-tjaLruCI&checkin=01-03-2017&checkout=15-03-2017&ss_id=augz4mpr&source=bb&page=1&s_tag=6nP_pE7j&allow_override%5B%5D=) Link is for first half of March.

[BeWelcome](http://www.bewelcome.org/searchmembers) "Step inside and invite travelers to your home, find hosts all over the world, and become part of our multicultural hospitality community. We are not-for-profit, open source, and exclusively run by members in a transparent and democratic way." May not offer much choice but is better than Couchsurfing International according to @WGroleau.

[Trustroots Foundation](https://www.trustroots.org/) Seems may require membership.

[Warm Showers](https://www.warmshowers.org/) "Hospitality For Touring Cyclists Worldwide." Seems may require membership. Might not be suitable for other than very short stays, by cyclists.

If the above official/commercial possibilities turn out fruitless a more informal approach to an association linking [Sweden and the Netherlands](http://www.swedenabroad.com/en-GB/Embassies/The-Hague/Contact/Swedish-associations-and-societies/) might turn up something - possibly in exchange for teaching some Dutch.

Other possibilities:

[The Hospitality Club](http://secure.hospitalityclub.org/hc/hcworld.php?country=185&language=eng).

[GlobalFreeloaders.com](http://www.globalfreeloaders.com/)

[Workaway.info](http://www.workaway.info/hostlist.html?showMoreOptions=0&ct=europe&country=SE&search=&page=hostlist&workawayer_capacity=0&host_rating=0)